# Job Websites for University Teachers

Tags: job-search, recruiting

What are the main websites teachers look to when searching a new university teaching job? If it varies by discipline, I'm talking about finance in particular but business in general would also be appropriate.

As far as location, I'm looking for teachers from the US or from the UK (but anyone with decent English skills would be considered) to come to beautiful Asia.

I saw [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/are-there-any-good-job-directories-for-academic-work) but it seems focused on research jobs (PhD positions, postdocs, etc.). I'm really looking for teachers to teach financial subjects.

Comment: jobs.ac.uk is pretty standard for research, teaching and admin academic jobs in the UK.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Thanks but I see they have a grand total of 29 jobs outside of Europe (Asia, Middle East, Africa, and Australasia). Is there no place with more of an international presence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question suggests that you want to find resources on how to find jobs in Asia. That's easy. Googling "Academic Positions Asia" found me this website ([www.unijiobs.asia](http://www.unijobs.asia/)), (on the first hit) which claims to be "Asia's University Jobs Portal."

This seems to be what you are looking for. The site seems to have a fairly comprehensive set of search tools, with the ability to do keyword searching or to search by position type, by discipline, or by location.

The end of your question suggests that you really want to find people to fill positions that you have. Listing on sites like I just found and like what you found will help, but in general, you need to advertise. The best advertising is to be had in the publications or on the website(s) of the professional organization(s) relevant to your discipline.

Comment: In terms of advertisements see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/are-pay-announcements-worth-their-price-to-hire-people